# Is it possible to load an external XML file in XNA?

Tags: xml, path, xna, load, external

In the past month I've learned how to use XML files in XNA, by adding them to the content folder (or project in XNA 4) and loading them in the LoadContent method.
I'd like to know if it is possible to load an external XML file, a "new" file that isn't in the content project, in the same way.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IntermediateSerializer` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.serialization.intermediate.intermediateserializer.aspx)) - it is exactly what XNA uses under-the-hood. It's in the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline` assembly.

The *very large* downside is that the content pipeline assemblies are only available with XNA **Game Studio**, and are not in the XNA **Framework** redistributable. So any code that references that assembly will only run on a devloper machine with Game Studio installed.

Depending on what you are trying to do, either this is unacceptable - and you'll have to use an alternative for XML serialization. Or if you are doing something like a level editor you can use the content pipeline directly to build XNB files - which can then be distributed and dynamically loaded. The [WinForms 2](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) sample explains how.

See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/05/07/effect-compilation-and-content-pipeline-automation-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Is it not possible to attach by reference the content pipeline assemblies to the project so that a copy of the dll will be made next to the executable?

Comment: There is no *technical* limitation on you doing that. However bundling the DLLs with your game violates the XNA Game Studio EULA. You can only distribute the XNA Framework installer (it is a "redistributable").

Comment: Holy crap. I knew your name was familiar. You're doing aweomse work on ExEn. truly.

Comment: And about the EULA... that's too bad. but I guess I'll just have to use System.Xml or some other Xml library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try XElement

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know I can use System.IO, System.Xml or other libraries. But what I'm really looking for is something (perhaps in XNA) with exactly the same one-line load method that XNA gives me.